# Differentiating between access from App Store application on MAC vs regular browser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, mac-app-store

I want to differentiate whether the user is accessing from "Go for Gmail" application on MAC or the regular Safari browser in javascript.
I checked the user agents and there are no clues / differences between the two.

Ex:
User Agent sent by "Go for Gmail" application on MAC is

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9`

User Agent sent by "Safari" browser on MAC is

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7`

Link to "Go for Gmail.app" on MAC : https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/go-for-gmail-email-client/id979538493?mt=12

I can't install any extension or plugins in them as these are owned by some other third party companies.

I am looking for some way in javascript to differentiate above two flows.
All this is needed because I noticed applications on MAC doesn't allow downloads and launching of custom URLs.
I think the applications on MAC use WebKit or WebUI with some limitations set.

Can someone please help me with differentiating these?

Thanks in advance...